# Efficient solution to linear system involving Kronecker sum in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, linear-solver

High dimensional finite difference problems often lead to linear systems of the form
$$
A x = b, \qquad A = B_1 \oplus B_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus B_d,
$$
where $\oplus$ denotes the Kronecker sum.  $B_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are 1D finite difference matrices, often tridiagonal or pentadiagonal.  When $d=2$, for example, this is
$$
A = B_1 \otimes I + I \otimes B_2.
$$

My question is about how to solve these systems most efficiently in MATLAB.  The simplest approach is to construct the matrices using `kron` and solve with `mldivide`, but these systems can have a large bandwidth.  In [How to efficiently invert $K \otimes M+I_T\otimes \Sigma$?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32724) and in the literature on Sylvester equations, I've come across more efficient approaches based on diagonalizations or Schur decompositions of $B_i$.  As $B_i$ are often Toeplitz or circulant, there are efficient FFT-based techniques for this, but I can't always make these structural assumptions.  If my understanding is correct, the cost of this is $O(d n^3 + n^d)$.

Is there a more efficient way to solve these Kronecker sum systems when $B_i$ are banded?  I speculate it is possible to do in $O(d n + n^d)$ time.  Can this problem be decomposed into a sequence of 1D linear solves which are easily handled with `mldivide`?

Answer (score 1):

They only deal with the 2D case, but I can point you to the work of some of my colleagues on https://doi.org/10.1137/17M1157155 . Using the off-diagonal low-rank structure in a recursive fashion, they can reach quasi-linear cost for the 2D case.